# Odd bison parsing

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

To pretext this, I understand that the formatting of the parse structure is weird, the teacher wanted it to be ~roughly~ in this format.

I'm making a simple "calculator" parser form an assignment using flex and bison, but I am getting odd or unusual output for the answer when using modulus. IT seems to work fine for all other operations

```
Input:   "10 % 5"
Output:  "  % 10"
Input:    "101 % 12"
Output:   "  % 101"
Input: "2^(-1 + 15/5) - 3*(4-1) + (-6)"
Output: "-11" //Correct
```

Relevant section of bison.y

```
command : pexpri    {printf("%d\n", $1); return;}
        ;

pexpri  : '-' expri '+' termi   {$$ = -$2 + $4;} /* Super glued on unary, also reduce conflict, TODO: find bug */
        | '-' expri '-' termi   {$$ = -$2 - $4;}
        | '-' expri             {$$ = -$2;}
        | expri                 {$$ = $1;}
        ;
expri   : expri '+' termi   {$$ = $1 + $3;} /* Addition subtraction level operations*/
        | expri '-' termi   {$$ = $1 - $3;}
        | termi             {$$ = $1;}
        ;
termi   : termi '*' factori     {$$ = $1 * $3;} /* Multiplication division level operations*/
        | termi '/' factori     {$$ = $1 / $3;}
        | termi '%' factori     {$$ = $1 % $3;}
        | factori               {$$ = $1;}
        ;
factori : factori '^' parti {$$ = pow($1, $3);} /* Exponentiation level operations */
        | parti             {$$ = $1;}
        ;
parti   : '(' pexpri ')'        {$$ = $2;} /* Parentheses handling or terminal, also adds even more reduction errors.... */
        | INTEGER
        ;
```

Relevant section tokenizer.l

```
0           { /* To avoid useless trailing zeros. */
                yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext);
                return INTEGER;
            }
[1-9][0-9]* {
                yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext);
                return INTEGER;
            }
[-()^\+\*/]         {return *yytext;}
```

The main function is essentially just a wrapper for yyparse.

I don't understand how or why it is printing the modulus symbol in the output because the ONLY print in the entire code is in the command section. I understand that the code isn't the best (in fact, it is awful), but any insight is much appreciated.

Also, if anybody can help me figure out how to manage unary negation in a more elegant way (Hopefully without spoiling much), that would also be super appreciated. (I cant just use %precidence or %left) The way I have it currently set up is ambiguous and is causing reduction errors.

Comment: Also, your two questions have no relationship with each other. SO prefers posts with just one question; that makes the question and its answer easier to discover with a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at

```
[-()^\+\*/]         {return *yytext;}
```

you'll notice that it is not going to match <kbd>%</kbd>. The most likely consequence is that (f)lex's default fallback rule will apply. That rule matches any single character and uses `ECHO` to copy the matched token to the output stream.

It looks to me like whitespace characters might also be falling through to the default rule. They should be ignored explicitly.

By the way, it is not necessary to backslash-escape regular expression operators inside character classes, since they have no special meaning in that context. Hence a correct and easier to read rule would be

```
[-+*/%^()]         {return *yytext;}
```

However, I strongly recommend using a fallback rule instead of listing all the possible single-character tokens. If an invalid single-character token is handled by a fallback rule, then the parser will respond by flagging an error.

```
[[:space:]]+      { /* Ignore whitespace*/ }
0|[1-9][0-9]*     { yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
.                 { return *yytext; /* Fallback rule */ }
```

The default fallback rule is rarely useful in parsing, and I find it useful to add

```
%option nodefault
```

to my flex prolog, which will cause flex to produce an error message if a fallback rule is required.

Comment: My god, I'm a dunce. I can't believe that I was struggling with something that wasn't technically even in the bounds of my assignment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @siech0: but you learned about (f)lex's default fallback rule, which is a very important thing to know about if you're going to use (f)lex. :-)